# Setting up Git correctly between Local, remote and repository

Tags: git, bitbucket, remote-server, atlassian-sourcetree, localserver

I've been playing about with Git for about a week or two but after many days reading, I still don't know how to actually set this up correctly.

I have set up a website project on my local server, installed git into the project folder and successfully pushed it to my bitbucket account I now have a clone of my project folder within Bitbucket and any changes will be uploaded once I add a commit.

So I now have a local server and a remote repository, What I don't understand is what I need to do no in regards to the remote server?

Should I be pushing to the remote server from my repository or my local server? and if so how?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know bitbucket, but could you try and click right on a file ? Maybe there's a commit and push option there.

Comment: Push where, back to my local server or the remote server? This is the part I cant find anywhere.

Comment: In Git you first commit locally. Then you push to the remote server.

Comment: So what about the remote repository? I was to believe that I push from the local server to the repository then push from the repository to the remote server? So confused about this part.

Comment: What is your IDE?  For instance in Visual Studio there's a publish function that publishes to the remote server from Visual Studio. There's also commit functionality withing VS, but thats separate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way to work is to have one place designated to just keeping your repository, in your case this would be Bitbucket. When you need to make changes, have a clone of the repository on your local development machine. Push changes back to the repository at Bitbucket as needed.

If more people need to work on the same project, they can easily clone the same repository from Bitbucket.

For deployment, either use a CI tool that will fetch from the Bitbucket repository and deploy, or write your own script that does something similar.

Comment: Thank you. But what is a CI tool? Is that Bitbucket Pipelines?

Comment: Travis CI, is one example.